# Fetching profile picture returns empty value

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to access my profile pic at a specified width & height, using PHP SDK via the following code:

```
$picture = $facebook->api('/me/picture', array('width'=>'160', 'height'=>'160'));
```

This gives a `null` array when dumped! But in GRAPH API Explorer, it was giving an array with the URL to the pic!

In API Explorer, this is what I used: `/me/picture?width=160&height=160`

Similarly, I tried to access just the picture, without passing any arguments. Same effect on that too!

Any idea on why it's happening so?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found it!

We have to add `redirect=false` parameter. Then only it would return the data!

Implementation using PHP SDK:

```
$picture = $facebook->api('/me/picture', array('width'=>'160', 'height'=>'160', 'redirect'=> 'false'));
```